# Explanation why dc-dc converter is a time-variant system

Tags: circuit-analysis, switch-mode-power-supply, dc-dc-converter, power-electronics, signal-theory

How do you explain that dc-dc converter is a time-variant system?

I see that there is an explanation as follows:

> dc-dc converter is a time-variant system because its topology changes
>   with time.

Do you agree with this? 
Is there another explanation?

Comment: That's nonsense.  The topology of a converter (e.g. buck, boost) is static.  Do you have a link to the source?  Or is this just a 'I heard it somewhere' question?

Comment: "Dc-to-dc converters are a time-variant system in the sense that the topological structure of their power stage constantly varies with time." - Pulsewidth Modulated Dc-to-Dc Power Conversion by Byungcho Choi

Comment: This is pretty clearly copied and pasted from a textbook, looking for stack exchange to do your homework for you?

Comment: No copy, paste and no homework at all. I am learning by myself. I am studying dc-dc converter from the book "Pulsewidth Modulated Dc-to-Dc Power Conversion by Byungcho Choi". The author mentioned that "Dc-to-dc converters are a time-variant system in the sense that the topological structure of their power stage constantly varies with time." So I wondered if this is the proper explanation for this. I think we can explain from the definition (using delay). However, I have no idea how to apply that to dc-dc converter because the transfer function is not clear.

Comment: @calcium3000: and here is the link: https://books.google.co.kr/books?id=3bU2AAAAQBAJ&pg=PP25&lpg=PP25&dq=Pulsewidth+Modulated+Dc-to-Dc+Power+Conversion&source=bl&ots=pP2MOMWrq1&sig=19qNMEmIqFMC2USBi5FuxCKHABo&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjPpNLKmafRAhVBPpQKHePeAeUQ6AEIYDAM#v=onepage&q=%22Dc-to-dc%20converters%20are%20a%20time-variant%20system%22&f=false

Comment: Okay, I get what he means.  I believe what he's getting at is the input-output relationship of the system changes, 'Depending on the status of the semiconductor devices.'  For example, in a buck converter the input current is either positive or zero depending on the state of the semiconductors (typically a MOSFET and a diode), whilst the output current is (ideally) constant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From a mathematical perspective, certain DC-DC converters can be considered time-varying systems. This is in contrast with *time-invariant* systems, which are frequently-used models in electrical engineering.

[Mathematically speaking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time-invariant_system), given a system whose input-output relationship is given by
$$
y(t) = T[x(t)]
$$
where $$T[\cdot]$$ is a functional representing the action of the system on input signal $$x(t)$$ and producing output signal $$y(t)$$

The system is time invariant if $$T[x(t-\tau)] = y(t-\tau)$$

Any converter that controls a switching transistor using a square-wave input, for instance, will be a time-varying system.  The action of turning a switch off and on with some frequency can be modeled as multiplying by a square-wave.

We will show how multiplying by a sinusoidal signal violates time-invariance. Because a square wave is simply a sum of sinusoidal signals, the result is applicable to square waves as well.  Consider the system 
$$
T[x(t)] = \cos(t) x(t) = y(t) 
$$
define
$$
g(t) = x(t-1) = x(t-1)
$$
and then apply this as the input to the system, therefore
$$
T[g(t)] = T[x(t-1)] = \cos(t) g(t) = \cos(t) x(t-1) \ne  y(t-1) 
$$
since
$$
y(t-1) = \cos(t-1) x(t-1)
$$

Therefore the system is time-varying.

With this in mind, it can be seen that a [buck-boost converter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buck%E2%80%93boost_converter) is time-varying, whereas a [voltage divider](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voltage_divider) is time-invariant.

Comment: "The action of turning a switch off and on with some frequency can be modeled as multiplying by a square-wave." - Can you show me where I can read the proof of this?

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is a mainly subjective question.

We have different models with different characteristics to represent the same thing in nature. Different models are useful for different goals.

We have the definition of time-invariance in terms of differential equations, and it involves using a model.

So, in the case of a DC-DC converter, you could have a time-invariant averaged model and say that it "is" the converter itself.

In the other extreme, pretty much everything could be represented as a time variant, non-linear system, if we have a sufficiently complex detailed model of it.

So in my opinion there is no right answer for it. It could and it could not. If you have a model with different equations depending on the state of the switching devices, then yes.

Answer (score 1):

You could say that the circuit topology changes when the switch opens and closes as below. When the switch is closed, the inductor is being charged, and when opened, discharged.

The diode could also be replaced by another switch operating opposite the first if you want a more "theoretical" circuit.

[image]

Because switches (transistors, diodes...) are non-linear devices, naive 'steady-state' analysis doesn't work, so maybe that quote is alluding to that you can't treat them like resistors and caps.